# Looking for maintained Select input JavaScript or jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

I am looking for JavaScript or jQuery plugin for nicer rendering of Selectbox input. So far I have found few (i.e. Chosen) but they are not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few jQuery-based plugins.

1. Select2

   [Website](https://select2.org) - [GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2) - Last update was on March 10, 2023.
2. Selectize

   [Website](https://selectize.dev) - [GitHub](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) - Last update was on March 1, 2023.
3. Selectric

   [Website](https://selectric.js.org) - [GitHub](https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric) - Last update was on January 12, 2018.